# reducing with a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension, reduce

Is there a better way of writing the following for loop?

```
my_list = []
for key in my_set_of_keys:
    for val1,val2 in my_dict[key]:
        my_list.append((key,val2,val1))
```

My attempts are perhaps ... a little rambling ...

```
my_list = list(chain.from_iterable(map(
    lambda key: [(key,val2,val1) for (val1,val2) in my_dict[key]],
    my_set_of_keys)))

my_list = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,(map(
    lambda key: [(key,val2,val1) for (val1,val2) in my_dict[key]],
    my_set_of_keys)))

my_list = reduce(list.__add__, (map(
    lambda key: [(key,val2,val1) for (val1,val2) in my_dict[key]],
    my_set_of_keys)))
```

my_dict looks like this:

```
'keyA' : { ('foo',1), ('bar',2), ('baz',3) }
'keyB' : { ... }
```

my_set_of_keys:

```
{ 'keyA', 'keyC', ... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
my_list = [(key, v2, v1) for key in my_set_of_keys for v1, v2 in my_dict[key]]
```

Comment: I had tried this before but I still get. `nodepaths = [(key,val2,val1) for val1,val2 in graph[key] for key in nodeset]
NameError: global name 'key' is not defined`

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: Try the solution from my answer. The issue is in fact the order of loops. This has to work, if you have `my_set_of_keys` and `my_dict` defined and with correct type.

Comment: i'll accept as soon as I can. That order has been throwing me of for ages! it is still backwards in my eyes... but works!